# Getting data from json wikivoyage with php

Tags: php, json

Pls find the json iam receiving:

```
 {  
 "batchcomplete":"",
 "continue":{  
  "sroffset":10,
  "continue":"-||"
  },
   "query":{  
  "searchinfo":{  
     "totalhits":1937
  },
  "search":[  
     {  
        "ns":0,
        "title":"India",
        "pageid":15557,
        "size":213703,
        "wordcount":30816,
        "snippet":"<span class=\"searchmatch\">India</span> (Hindi: \u092d\u093e\u0930\u0924 or Bharat) is the largest country in the Indian subcontinent and shares borders with Pakistan to the northwest, China and Nepal to",
        "timestamp":"2018-05-27T12:16:15Z"
     },
     {  
        "ns":0,
        "title":"Southern India",
        "pageid":33554,
        "size":20350,
        "wordcount":2534,
        "snippet":"South <span class=\"searchmatch\">India</span> includes five major states in peninsular <span class=\"searchmatch\">India</span> and the two island groups of Lakshadweep in the Arabian Sea on the West Coast of <span class=\"searchmatch\">India</span> and Andaman",
        "timestamp":"2018-05-13T14:30:50Z"
     }}
```

Iam trying to retrieve the data using php.

My PHP code is below.

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&srsearch=India&format=json');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$xml = curl_exec ($curl);  

if ($xml === false) {
    die('Error fetching data: ' . curl_error($curl));  
}

curl_close ($curl); 

echo htmlspecialchars("$xml", ENT_QUOTES);

$data = json_decode($xml); 
foreach ($data->query as $country) 
{ 
    echo $country->searchinfo; 
}
```

But iam getting an error in this line..echo $country->searchinfo; The error states that Undefined property: stdClass::$searchinfo.

I am trying to retrieve only the snippet variable (first one)

Can someone help me.

Comment: Are you certain it's meant to be `$data->queryfo` and not `$data->query`?

Comment: sorry. It was a type mistake. its is "query".

Comment: Is this the JSON you actually receive, though? It contains syntax errors that make decoding it impossible.

Comment: Iam receiving the json data from this link. https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&srsearch=India&format=json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`$data->queryfo` needs to be `$data->query`

2.You have to change `foreach()` like this:-

```
foreach ($data->query->search as $country) 
{ 
    echo $country->snippet;echo PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Note:- I have changed the code as you said `I am trying to receive the snippet and not totalhits`

Comment: @Sanju  glad to help you :):)